# Passing value to ng-model in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Right, I'm probably missing something fairly obvious here but here goes. I have a bit of HTML from bootstrap that I want to reuse so I wanted to make it into a custom directive.

```
<label class="toggle">
<input ng-model='model' type="checkbox" class="toggleInput">
    <div class="track">
        <div ng-show="test" class="toggle-label on">
            {{onText}}
        </div>
        <div ng-show="!test" class="toggle-label off">
            {{offText}}
        </div>
    <div class="handle"></div>
</div></label>
```

snippet of html I want to use in my pages that Angular will recompile into the above:

```
<toggle on-text="On" off-text="Off" ng-model="myModelName"></toggle>
```

My directive is as follows:

```
.directive('toggle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'views/toggle.view.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            onText: '@',
            offText: '@',
            ngModel : '=',
        },
    };
});
```

However, when looking at the html markup the ng-model attribute has not changed to 'myModelName' and still shows just 'modal' so hasn't updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`<input ng-model='model' type="checkbox" class="toggleInput">`

with

`<input ng-model='{{ngModel}}' type="checkbox" class="toggleInput">`

because you want to bind the value of the incoming model name into the ng-model attribute of the template inside the directive.

Comment: Sorry I should of said I tried that but that errors as you can't use an expression in ng-model. Error is: "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'ngModel' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{ngModel}}] starting at [ngModel}}]"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.... used compile in the link function to dynamically add the model to the elements I needed:

```
return $compile($('input.toggleInput',element).attr('ng-model', model))(scope);
```